# Change pictureBox1 properties in Timer method

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

So I have this awesome pictureBox1 in my C# program. Every 5 second I call an time method like this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
    aTimer.Interval = 2000;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
}

private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{ 
}
```

I am trying to change a property of a pictureBox object I got. But I get this error when trying to do so:

> Error  1   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Simma.Form1.pictureBox1' C:\Users\John\Desktop\Simma\Simma\Form1.cs  39  13  Simma

The pictureBox1 is set to Public though.

Comment: where is the code where you are trying to modify the picture box?

Answer (score 1):

The problem must be in the code you haven't shown us... presumably in `OnTimedEvent`.

The simplest fix is to make `OnTimedEvent` an instance method instead. This isn't a matter of accessibility (and the field *shouldn't* be public - make it private!) it's a matter of trying to use an *instance* field from a *static* method.

Note, however, that you *also* shouldn't try to access a UI element from a non-UI thread. Currently your timer will fire its event in a different thread, causing cross-thread issues.

The simplest fix for this is to use a [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) instead of a `System.Timers.Timer`.